# What are the options for connect username/password@sid in a sql script for jdbc

Tags: oracle, jdbc, database-connection

I have sql scripts which was intended to execute using sql command line(oracle 11g). I am porting these scirpts to work with java/jdbc. My concern is the script is using `connect username/password@sid` to connect to other schemas for operations like create a view in main schema which is having table objects from different schemas. What can be the option to connect things when using jdbc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you change your schema if you are specifying as a prefix and both of schema is on the same instance/SID as below:

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = <schema name>
```

Else, Other I can suggest you create a DB link and use that DB link with an object to create or access the object in a different schema.

Example: within schema-1

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK connec_to_schema_2 ....
```

To create object use like:

```
CREATE VIEW view_name_1@connect_to_schema_2
AS
<SQL Statement>....
```

To access the object from schema_2 you can use the same syntax as:

```
SELECT FROM view_name_1@connect_to_schema_2;
```

Comment: Thank you Vivek. I tried DB link way and it is working fine.

Comment: If information is useful you can vote up and mark it answered

Comment: Yes Vivek the information is useful and I marked it as answered. I don't have enough reputation to upvote. This is my first question on stackover flow and I am very thankful for your help.